# How to improve time to execute logging stored procedure in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory

I have an ADF solution which is metadata driven. It passes a connection string, and source and sink as parameters. My concern is that I also have SQL logging steps within pipelines and child pipelines and now for a simple Azure DB table copy into ADSL Parquet it is bottlenecked by the logging steps and child pipelines. I noticed that each step (mainly logging steps) take around 3-6 seconds.

I have tried the following:

- upgrading the config database from basic to S1
- changing the ADF's integration runtime to 32 core count
- changing the TTL to 20 mins
- checked the quick cache

Nothing seems to reduce the time to run these audit steps.

The audit step is a stored procedure which you pass in a load of parameters. This proc run in split seconds in SSMS so the proc isn't the issue.

Is there any way of reducing the time to execute logging steps?

Comment: Can you tell us what kind of information you are logging? What are you missing from the standard ADF logging?

Comment: Yes this is an issue - the ADF stored proc task has a lot of overhead.

Comment: Perhaps when the OP says logging they mean, as an example writing a high water mark to a control table.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Microsoft SLA for ADF, they guarantee that at least 99.9% of the time, all activity runs will initiate within 4 minutes of their scheduled execution times.

**As stated from the Product Team, any stored procedure activity that performs within 4 minutes has met SLA within ADF--this SLA covers the overhead of ADF communicating with SQL server. With that said, your current performance within ADF is normal.**

Check the supported documents:

1. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/support/legal/sla/data-factory/v1_2/
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/36323/adf-performance-troubleshooting.html

Answer (score 0):

I tend to think adding excessive logging into pipelines is a bit of an anti-pattern as it leads to more complex pipelines with more components to maintain.  You can also encounter this type of issue, particularly if you're running the logging inside a For Each activity for example.  I tend to use this sparingly and concentrate more on the built-logging and making use of the custom [user properties and annotations](https://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/annotations-user-properties-azure-data-factory/).  Most of the information you need should be in the built-in logging which you can harvest via API calls either at the end of your pipelines or elsewhere, as ably described [here](https://datasavvy.me/2020/12/24/retrieving-log-analytics-data-with-data-factory/) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-logs-rest).

The other thing you could do is move any non-critical tasks to run in parallel.  For example a 'log start of activity' task does not necessarily need to run first sequentially.  Consider making some of these tasks non-parallel, as explained in the diagram below.  Obviously this does **not** apply when you need to capture information from the activity to log:

[image: sequential v parallel tasks]

Comment: Any update on this please?